# DownloadTask never gets contents and crashes the app

Tags: java, android

Im trying to get a website content but my app keeps crashing on upon calling DownloadTask

This is my DownloadTask and onCreate code

and the debug also goes to Log.i and my guess is that the result string isnt getting the content ? or the downloadtask code is all wrong?

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        String result = "";
        try {
            url = new URL(urls[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
            int data = reader.read();
            while  (data !=1) {
                char current = (char) data;
                result += current;
                data = reader.read();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

"onCreate"

```
    DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
    String result = null;
    try {
        result = task.execute("https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&appid=API_KEY/").get();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i("Contents", result);
```

Comment: Where are the logs?

Comment: 1. `AsyncTask.get()` ? then why are you using AsyncTask at all ... 2. why are you reading byte by byte? 3. `while  (data !=1) ` ??? please read doc for `InputStreamReader.read()`

Comment: Why are you guessing? log variables, run in debug mode, etc . there are ways to check things

Comment: Because you are using `.get()` which blocks your main thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out

I didn't add return result; to the code, adding it fixed my problem.

```
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        String result = "";
        try {
            url = new URL(urls[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
            int data = reader.read();
            while (data != -1) {
                char current = (char) data;
                result += current;
                data = reader.read();
            }
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```